# How to rotate a string fixing the right side of it on the X axis using C3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            x : 'x',
            columns: [
                ['x', 'AE009948','AL732656','CP000114'],
                ['Core', 30, 200, 250],
                ['Shared', 10, 100, 100],
                ['Exclusive', 70, 10 100]
            ],
            type: 'bar',
        },
        title: {
              text: 'random'
            },
        axis:{
            x:{
                type:'category',
                tick: {
                    rotate: 30,
                    multiline: false
                },
                height:100
            }
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
            }
            // or
            //width: 100 // this makes bar width 
        }
```

The tick {rotate: 30} rotates clockwise fixing the string 'A' of 'AE009948' ,
I'd like to rotate fixing the end of the string, which is '8' in 'AE009948'. 
There's no documentation on this...http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-rotated

Comment: can you please the whole example of your code so we can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **negative value** for rotation.

```
axis:{
    x:{
        tick: {
            rotate: -30
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/2vkgxtho/3/).